# How do I run chef recipes after app server is fired up

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, composer-php, chef-recipe, chef-solo

Using Amazons OpsWorks

I'm able to get a PHP App Server to get initialised, it downloads our project from git and sets it up, I've got a custom recipe being run on `Setup` that works and downloads `composer`, but this gets run before the git repository is downloaded, so too early to try and change permissions.

I've currently got a recipe in `Deploy` that changes permissions on some files that were created as part of downloading our git project, however this recipe doesn't seem to get fired when setting up a new instance, I can only run it by manually deploying an app.

How can I have a recipe run after the git project has been downloaded by chef, when an instance is created (so when the site auto scales and a new instance is fired up, the recipe is run to set file permissions correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because opsworks is currently in beta there are still a few issues, there is an issue with deployments. Apparently custom deployments are not run when initialising a new php instance (not sure about others as I have only used php)

Answer (score 1):

today in OpsWorks the "setup" event means: OpsWorks setup chef recipes, customer setup chef recipes, OpsWorks deploy chef recipes

We're planning to change this so that "setup" event means: OpsWorks setup chef recipes, customer setup chef recipes, OpsWorks deploy chef recipes, customer deploy chef recipes

Comment: @Chrisb Any word on when this will be happening, seems like something that would be expected and used heavily by other developers wanting to deploy / scale their apps, definitely something that's a barrier for us

Answer (score 1):

We have addressed this issue. Custom deploy recipes are now run at instance boot.